# Run Java Project from Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, boot

I have a small java project that handle connections. 
In order to run it from the terminal I have to cd into the folder that contains the source and run the following command:

```
java -cp classes com.packagename.mainclass
```

Where classes is the folder that contains the classes.

I want ubuntu to run this application on startup, is there a Java command I can use? Or am I just better off creating a shell script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### On system boot:

Add to the end of `/etc/rc.local`:

```
(cd ~your_username/path_to_source/ && sudo -u your_username java -cp ...) &
```

(It might be better to create [an Upstart job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) instead.)

#### On logon:

Open "System - Preferences - Startup Programs" (`gnome-session-preferences`) and add your program there.

Comment: Can you add a java program to Startup programs, I assume it needs to be compiled to a JAR first?

Comment: @Christopher: But you can add the `java` command.